# Make converted joomla template show 2 colums in main content

Tags: php, html, css, joomla

I have converted a html/css template into a joomla template following these steps: http://www.tobacamp.com/tutorial/5-easy-steps-converting-html-template-to-joomla-template/.

However it doesn't say anything about how to make the main content show two or three columns instead of one (like a newspaper etc).

I want the main content of my Joomla Home page to show articles in 2 or three columns.IN THE MAIN CONTENT only.

I have tried everything and doesn't work.

What php or css code i have to enter in order to have my articles showed in 2-3 columns in the main content, and not  one under the another

Comment: Please see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500346/how-to-make-my-converted-joomla-template-content-show-2-or-3-columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not supported by all browsers, you can (should) use [CSS Multi Columns](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-multicol/) for that purpose. It works with IE10+, Opera 11.1+ (standard syntax) and Firefox 2+, Chrome 4+, Safari 3.1+ (vendor prefix). For other browsers, you can utilize a [JS library](http://www.csscripting.com/css-multi-column/).

### Example Usage

#### HTML (index.php)

```
...
<jdoc:include type="message" />
<div id="content">
    <jdoc:include type="component" />        
</div>
...
```

#### CSS

```
#content {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-width: 75px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
    -webkit-column-rule: 1px solid #fff;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-width: 75px;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    -moz-column-rule: 1px solid #fff;
    -o-column-count: 3;
    -o-column-width: 75px;
    -o-column-gap: 20px;
    -o-column-rule: 1px solid #fff;
    column-count: 3;
    column-width: 75px;
    column-gap: 20px;
    column-rule: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

Comment: You reckon it will work only with css code? Doesn't need any phhp code too?                                        My index.php page is like this:

  <div class="grid_3" >
        <?php if($this->countModules('position-1') ) : ?>
               <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-1" style="xhtml" />
               <?php endif; ?>
                        <jdoc:include type="message" />
                   <jdoc:include type="component" />
                        
          </div>

Where does the css code help? Sorry for aksing i am a bit novice at css

Comment: Added an example for better understanding.

Comment: If you set the column parameters, for the home page menu items, you'll see the markup in the page change accordingly. You can style those classes to layout as you desire. See http://docs.joomla.org/Help25:Menus_Menu_Item_Article_Featured#Layout_Options

Comment: Please could you send me the entire css additions? From what i have understanded it needs only css changes. Nor php code needed. Is that true?

Comment: This is not a 1-to-1 support forum, sorry. All you need is in my answer. And yes, it is just adjusting the `index.php` and adding the CSS to the corresponding CSS file.